# Why Selection.objects not selecting object in hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of Object which i am assigning into [**Selection.objects**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-objects.html) in order to select it in hierarchy. But the problem is it is not selecting every objects but showing this  collectively in in the inspector.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the PropertyAttribute "Selection Base" https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SelectionBaseAttribute.html? Or am I perhaps unfamiliar to "Selection.objects"..?

Comment: FYI! https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-objects.html